# record cellmouseclicks in a datagridview - use indexes of clicks made in datagridview as indexes in a matrix or array

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vba, datagridview, click

I hope you could help me. Many thanks in advance.

My question is related with catching the number of mouseclicks in a datagridview. I am using Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2012.

I am building a matrix or array with size 10x10 populated by 1's.
Also I have a datagridview with the same size.
My aim is to put a zero in the place of the matrix which has the same coordinates "rowindex" and "columnindex" as the click performed using the mouse in the datagridview.
Till this point I am having success.

But I want to go further:
I want to have as many zeros in the 1's matrix as clicks on the datagridview. My problem is that I can only have one zero, the last one.

If I perform a click in datagridview(1,1), datagridview(2,2) and datagridview(3,3) I only have finally a zero in the place (3,3)

I am not able to record the clicks made.

Here you have my code:

```
      Private Sub ClickMouse(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView.CellMouseClick
    MsgBox(e.Clicks & e.ColumnIndex & e.RowIndex)
    Dim matrix As Integer(,) = PopulateMatrix()

    matrix(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex) = 0

    Matrixtomatrixdef(matrix)
End Sub
Private Function PopulateMatrix() As Integer(,)  
    Dim matrix(10, 10) As Integer
    For rown = 0 To 9
        For columnn = 0 To 9
            matrix(columnn, rown) = 1
        Next
    Next
    Return matrix
End Function
Private Sub Matrixtomatrixdef(matrix As Integer(,))     
    Dim Matrixdef(10, 10) As Integer
    For rown = 0 To 9
        For columnn = 0 To 9
            Matrixdef(columnn, rown) = matrix(columnn, rown)
            Debug.Write(Matrixdef(columnn, rown).ToString & " ")
        Next
        Debug.WriteLine("")
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define and populate your matrix as a global variable, not inside your ClickMouse event handler (otherwise every click that occurs deletes the zeros you set in the previous one, leaving only the last one)

```
Public Class Form1
    Private matrix As Integer(,) = PopulateMatrix()

    Private Sub ClickMouse(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView.CellMouseClick
        MsgBox(e.Clicks & e.ColumnIndex & e.RowIndex)

        matrix(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex) = 0

        Matrixtomatrixdef(matrix)
    End Sub

    Private Function PopulateMatrix() As Integer(,)  
        Dim matrix(10, 10) As Integer
        For rown = 0 To 9
            For columnn = 0 To 9
                matrix(columnn, rown) = 1
            Next
        Next
        Return matrix
    End Function

    Private Sub Matrixtomatrixdef(matrix As Integer(,))     
        Dim Matrixdef(10, 10) As Integer
        For rown = 0 To 9
            For columnn = 0 To 9
                Matrixdef(columnn, rown) = matrix(columnn, rown)
                Debug.Write(Matrixdef(columnn, rown).ToString & " ")
            Next
            Debug.WriteLine("")
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrea, I made what you propose but an error appears which is related, from my point of view, with defining the matrix as a global variable.  When I press Start in "Visual Studio 2011 Ultimate 12", where I am working, it says: "InvalidOperationException was unhandled, an exception was caught by the debugger, and user settings indicate that a break should occur. This thread is stopped with only external code frames on the call stack. External code frames are typically from framework code but can also include other optimized modules which are loaded in a target process." What can I do?

Comment: Where are you having this unhandled exception? Try to debug the code to understand where the exception happens (I built a sample project and actually tried the code: it works as intended)

Comment: Hi @Andrea. For avoiding this error I only had to declare matrix as a global variable ["Private matrix as integer(,)"] but not ["Private matrix As Integer(,) = PopulateMatrix()"]. I have given Matrix its value inside the next Sub. This way it works. I do appreciate your effort.